# Remove punctuation from text (except the symbol &)

Tags: r, regex, string

I need to remove punctuation from the text:

```
 data <- "Type the command AT&W enter. in order to save the new protocol on modem;"
 gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',data)
```

This solution gives the result

```
[1] "Type the command AT W enter in order to save the new protocol on modem "
```

This is not the desired result because I would like to save `&`, hence:

```
[1] "Type the command AT&W enter in order to save the new protocol on modem "
```

Comment: You can specify the symbols you like removed separated by `|`: `gsub('\\.|;', ' ', data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing the inverse? i.e. replacing everything that is not a letter, a digit or a `&` with an empty string:

```r
gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]&]", "", data)
# [1] "Type the command AT&W enter in order to save the new protocol on modem"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try a user defined regex consisting of anything that is not an $ or an alpha numeric:

```
data <- "Type the command AT&W enter. in order to save the new protocol on modem;"

gsub('[^&[:alnum:] ]+',' ',data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another regex, which literally means "find all punctuations except `&`".

```
gsub("[^\\P{P}&]", "", data, perl = T)
[1] "Type the command AT&W enter in order to save the new protocol on modem"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `stringr`:

```r
library(stringr)
 
str_remove_all(data, "(?!&)[[:punct:]]")

#> [1] "Type the command AT&W enter in order to save the new protocol on modem"
```